# How to get the XML out parameter in a storedprocedure with simpleJdbcCall

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc

I have a procedure that returns a XML and I'm using simpleJdbcCall to execute it. When I get the result as a map, it returns a SQLServerSQLXML. I cast it to a java.sql.SQLXML to use the getString() method but with no sucess. It throws a NegativeArraySize exception. When I execute the procedure in SQLServer Management Studio it works and generates the XML.

I've already tried to get the binary stream but no sucess, It returned me only two unicode chars: `ÿ` (255) and `þ` (254).

This is my SimpleJdbcCall:

```
SimpleJdbcCall simpleCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)                                               
                        .withCatalogName("dbo")                          
                        .withProcedureName("pProcName")                                          
                        .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()                                          
                        .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("@ID", Types.BIGINT))                                        
                        .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("@XmlOut", Types.SQLXML));
```

I've set the ID and put it on a MapSqlParameterSource then I execute the procedure:

```
MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();

params.addValue("@ID", inDTO.getIdCertificado()); 

Map<String, Object> mapa = simpleCall.execute(params);
SQLXML xml = (SQLXML) mapa.get("@XmlOut");
String val = xml.getString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get working with inputstream. It seems that the pointer is at the end, so what I just had to do is reset it and parse my xml to a document:

```
InputStream binaryStream = xml.getBinaryStream();
binaryStream.reset();
DocumentBuilder parser = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document result = parser.parse(binaryStream);
```

Then just work with it to get my attributes and values.